# AssertJ-DB freezes in Spring Boot integration test

Tags: spring, junit, spring-transactions, assertj

I have the following integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class ServiceTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceUnderTest service;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Changes changes = new Changes(new Table(datasource, "SOME_TABLE"));
        changes.setStartPointNow();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
         service.doSomething();
         changes.setEndPointNow();
         // assert database changes with changes object
    }
}
```

When I run this test it freezes on changes startpoint line in @Before method:

```
changes.setStartPointNow();
```

I've figured out that test freezes in `org.assertj.db.type.Changes#setStartPointNow` on `t.getRowsList();` line, but I don't know how to solve it.

When I remove `@Transactional` annotation, everything works fine, nothing freezes, but test doesn't work properly then.

Is there any way to solve this problem preserving `@Transactional` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Changes changes = new Changes(new Table(datasource, "SOME_TABLE")).setStartPointNow();

     service.doSomething();

     changes.setEndPointNow();
     // assert database changes with changes object
}
```

Comment: the problem still appears, could you explain what is the main change in your approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was big table. I was watching changes on table with more than 10 000 rows.

> Changes changes = new Changes(new Table(source,
>   "big_table")).setStartPointNow();

When I changed it to:

> Request request1 = new Request(source, 
>                   "select * from big_table where some_column is null");

SQL returns less than 100 rows.

Changes start working fast. When changes was watching on table time was between 17-25 seconds. With request is less than 0,2s.